# What is placement id for rev mob

Tags: iphone, revmob

I try looking for information on it , but I still don't understand clearly on what it is. Mainly what is it use for in iPhone development?

Comment: Have you checked the details on - http://sdk.revmob.com/ios#placement

Answer (score 0):

Placement id is the way that you can identify an ad inside your app.
With this you'll be able to see individual statistics and have control of this specific ad (play an pause).

For example, if you want to place an fullscreen at the end of your game stage but you are not sure if is a good place. You can set a placement id to this ad and check the statistics to evaluate if it is a good idea. If it isn't performing well you can pause only this ad without have to submit a new version or pause all the ads.